# javascript: rounding a float UP to nearest .25 (or whatever...)

Tags: javascript, jquery

All answers I can find are rounding to nearest, not up to the value... for example

```
1.0005 => 1.25  (not 1.00)
1.9   => 2.00
2.10 => 2.25
2.59 => 2.75   etc.
```

would seem to be pretty basic, but this has me stumped.
But this has to round up, not to nearest, which is a relatively easy thing to do.

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: multiply by 4 => round => divide by 4

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Divide the number by `0.25` (or whatever fraction you want to round nearest to).

Round up to nearest whole number.

Multiply result by `0.25`.

```
Math.ceil(1.0005 / 0.25) * 0.25
// 1.25

Math.ceil(1.9 / 0.25) * 0.25
// 2

// etc.
```

```js
function toNearest(num, frac) {
  return Math.ceil(num / frac) * frac;
}

var o = document.getElementById("output");

o.innerHTML += "1.0005 => " + toNearest(1.0005, 0.25) + "<br>";
o.innerHTML += "1.9 => " + toNearest(1.9, 0.25) + "<br>";
o.innerHTML += "2.10 => " + toNearest(2.10, 0.25) + "<br>";
o.innerHTML += "2.59 => " + toNearest(2.59, 0.25);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Built a fiddle saw you already answered it, will share it here https://jsfiddle.net/8s9r16cr/

Comment: yep... just figured this out after coding it up in a php test. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the number by 4, use Math.ceil on the result and then divide that number by 4.

Answer (score 1):

Just multilpy by 4 and take the ceiled value with 4 times.

```js
var values = [1.0005, 1.9, 2.10, 2.59],
    round = values.map(function (a) { return Math.ceil(a * 4) / 4; });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(round, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Other divide and multiply will not work for some values such as 1.59 You can try customRound function

```
function customRound(x) {
    var rest = x - Math.floor(x)

    if (rest >= 0.875) {
        return Math.floor(x) + 1
    } else if (rest >= 0.625) {
        return Math.floor(x) + 0.75
    } else if (rest >= 0.375) {
        return Math.floor(x) + 0.50
    }  else if (rest >= 0.125){
        return Math.floor(x) + 0.25
    } else {
        return Math.floor(x)
    }
}
```